# Can I expect a seg fault if I overflow the stack

Tags: c++, centos, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, centos5

I have a program written in C++, compiled with gcc 4.8.1, running on CentOS 5. Under certain circumstances it runs into infinite recursion and typically causes a seg fault. Can I count on this to happen every time or could the behavior potentially be different from execution to execution, including scary scenarios such as corrupt data and application continuing to run seemingly as normal?

I am aware the consequence of stack overflow in general is undefined, I am just wondering if the outcome is somewhat deterministic given the OS is CentOS 5.

Comment: Please tell us that this is just for a toy program and you will never ever let anyone other than yourself run it or see the source code!   My mind is filled with visions of airplanes crashing, financial markets imploding, and a middle of the night phone call someday asking me to fix some program that "has been running just fine until now."

Comment: The scenario is actually purely hypotetical, even if the environment is not made up. I recently joined a workshop where it was discussed whether or not you can count on a program to crash or if might actually continue running and doing things you did not expect. This was a scenario that was never brought up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given CentOS is a Linux/GNU OS, you can count on it to generate a SIGSEGV... when you go to access pages off the end of the stack, that's what the OS will signal you with.

(Note that this is very different to a buffer overrun, which is another way in which the stack may encounter problems: in that case it's usually an array on the stack which is indexed beyond its end address - too far and it might generate a SIGSEGV too, but in other addresses it allows access to other data on the stack, such as function parameters, saved register values and return addresses.  That issue has subtler manifestations such as data corruption and security problems.)

Comment: And what if it happens in one of POSIX threads created by a program but not in its main thread?

Comment: @skwllsp: that's discussed in the NOTES section [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setguardsize.3.html) - summarily - SIGSEGV unless the apps deliberately asked for no guard pages, or is allocating variables on the stack larger than a page such that it might skip the guard page and find accessible memory beyond.